# XMLSchema 0.8.0 Error in R 3.2.0 on Windows

Tags: r, xmlschemaset

I'm trying to install the development version ([v. 0.8.0](http://www.omegahat.org/Prerelease/)) of XMLSchema in R 3.2.0 on a Windows 64-bit computer.
Unfortunately, the release version ([v. 0.7.0](http://www.omegahat.org/XMLSchema/)) doesn't work for the [database](http://www.marinespecies.org/aphia.php?p=webservice&type=r) I am trying to access.
However, when I try to install 0.8.0 from source, I get the following error:

```
> install.packages("XMLSchema", type="source", repos = NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Will/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'XMLSchema' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in .mergeMethodsTable(generic, mtable, tt, attach) : 
  trying to get slot "defined" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'C:/Users/Will/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/XMLSchema'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Will\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "XMLSchema"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘XMLSchema’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any thoughts or insight would be greatly appreciated.
The package worked for previous versions of R, perhaps it's a compatibility problem?
Thanks.

Comment: FYI...I'm on a 64 bit windows machine using Rstudio running R 3.1.3 and have XMLSchema v 0.7.0 installed. I just tried installing v 0.8.0 with no problems. good luck. seems like a version compatibility issue.

Comment: Yeah, I had v. 0.8.0 installed under R 3.1.3, but no luck with R 3.2.0.